# Why is the preview lay-out of my screen not the same as in Run-mode in Android Studio 3+

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently following a course about creating Android Apps but something bothers me:

Why is my run mode screen not the same as my preview lay-out screen in Android Studio?

[image]

Comment: Suggest posting your code if you want feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that each element did not have a marge. I added all top marges **(Select element --> add top margin)** on all the elements in which it solved the question.